# Question got deleted by owner after I answered, but I can still see it

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions

I answered the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58009694/indexing-is-not-working-in-object-array-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment102424497_58009694), and the user deleted their question about an hour after getting my answer.

My question is not what to do about it, although I am annoyed it got deleted, I was actually surprised that I could still see the question. I thought to see deleted questions, I need to have 10k in reputation, and as far as I can see, I am still somewhat far from it :)

So, why can I see this question in particular, is there a change to the availability of deleted questions for users that answered on them?

To go to the question in my case, I just clicked on one of the comments I had received from the user in my inbox. I cannot see the question on the users profile, nor on my all actions profile

[image]

Comment: As a <10k user, you can see deleted questions if you have an answer to it

Comment: @Zoe Since when? It's not the first time this has happened, and I remember getting the *voluntarily removed by the user* page when that happened

Comment: At least a couple years. No idea tbh.

Comment: @Icepickle see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125828/view-my-deleted-question-and-answer-with-less-than-10k/179511#179511

Comment: @psubsee2003 You were right, but the real information seemed to have been [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16841/should-i-be-able-to-access-a-deleted-question) :)

Comment: Could people please not downvote the users other post, my question was not based on revenge, but pure interests, and maybe, I should not have commented on the users other newest question, but that I will delete now as well, as I don't feel that either of the questions has something to do with the other, I just wanted to contact that person

Comment: @Zoe How would one then normally access the deleted answer, if you cannot find it under your own profile?

Comment: @Icepickle that's unfortunately not easy. If you had votes on your answer at the time of deletion, assuming you check "see deleted posts", you can back-trace your posts through the reputation tab. If it's recently deleted, you can click "See recently deleted questions"/"See recently deleted answers". When you hit 10k, you can search for `deleted:yes`. Storing the URL manually is an option too

Comment: @Zoe Thanks, I guess I should investigate that a bit. What mainly surprised me is that I still had the inbox message from that user. On the website I normally don't see notifications from deleted posts anymore (and also only 1 message remained, the other ones got deleted, maybe that should be my bug report ^_^) (it didn't have any votes btw, it didn't stay up long enough for that I believe)

Comment: You're only, what, 200 rep away?

Comment: @JL2210 Well, my rep doesn't change that fast ^_^ that's like months away

Comment: @Icepickle It is? 8 days later...

Comment: @JL2210 ^_^ I guess I got a bit lucky there :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/) (emphasis mine):

> If you don't have the moderator tools privilege, you can see any of your own questions that you have the direct link to, and your own deleted answers to any question. Additionally, **you can see any deleted question you have answered as well as your answer(s) to it provided you have the direct link**, but you can't see other users' answers to it, neither can you see the question's revision history.

Comment: Oh, that's a great answer, I guess I overlooked that when researching it (to be fair, I only checked the access moderator tools privilige)

Answer (score 9):

This is a feature that was implemented in 2017.  To quote Shog9's answer to the MSE post annoucing this feature

> Authors of deleted answers have always been able to see them*. As of a few weeks ago, authors of deleted questions can now view them as well, regardless of reputation.
>
> As of February 28th, 2017, authors of answers to deleted questions can also view them. Kudos to Konamiman and Nick Craver for making that work after many years of requests!
>
> *well, not quite always, but for several years now.

Quoted from [View *my* deleted question and answer with less than 10K](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125828/view-my-deleted-question-and-answer-with-less-than-10k/179511#179511)

Comment: Great info, this combined with the one from Jeanne Dark would be a perfect answer ^_^